# EnableViewState and ViewStateMode not working

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working in C#.Net and Framework 4.0. I am having a aspx and ascx pages. In my ascx, i am generating a XML and binding that XML value to Treeview. These are done in code behind. i am calling this ascx in my aspx page.

My issue is, i am having large volume of XML Data. Because of this, the performance of the page is very slow. I tried with enableviewstate and viewstatemode. But nothing works for me.

Still the viewstate is holding large volume of XML Data. I dont want this XML Data to be in viewstate.

How to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast, i had done with a temporary fix..Cleared the controls viewstate value in JQuery..This process had be done in submit button onclientclick.

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TreeView').empty();
```

And, out side the postback in pageload, i had again generated the XML value